# An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file xxxx failed

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a database file (FinanceDB.mdf) stored on the local harddrive. I can connect to the file, but when I execute queries to it through C#, I get the following error:

> An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file F:\IT7x01Project\App_Data\FinanceDB.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

I have set the permissions for everyone on the file to full access which I thought may be part of the problem, but it turns out that its not (unless there is more to it than just setting the permissions).

This is the connection string:

```
<add name="FinanceDBConnectionString1" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=F:\IT7x01Project\App_Data\FinanceDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

try to create connection string in  this format

```
<add name="Connec" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=C:\USERS\dL\DESKTOP\DATABASE\MYSHOP.MDF;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

(or)

Try setting the User Instance property in your connection string to true.

```
User Instance=True
```

Also just to be sure check again weather your database server already contain a database with the same name.

Comment: If I set `User Instance` to `True`, I get the following error: *The user instance login flag is not allowed when connecting to a user instance of SQL Server. The connection will be closed.*

Comment: Did anyone ever find a solution that doesn't require specifying the full file-name?

Answer (score -1):

```
<add name="Connections" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

add in we.config file